# Can I disable my wifi device driver from my application?

Tags: wifi, driver, root

I have root access on a proprietary system. I am trying to "securely" disable wifi by either renaming or removing the device driver file "wlan.ko" in folder /system/lib/modules.  I figured out how to do this using commands through a shell/console basically like so:

```
su

#first make the partition writable as follows: 
mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p5 /system

#go to the folder: 
cd /system/lib

# apply permissions
chmod -R 777 modules

cd modules

#rename the driver 
mv wlan.ko wlanko.ok
```

Now, I need to be able to do the same thing by executing the shell commands from within my Android application.  Looking at logcat output, it seems that I can't get past the chmod command.

Is this a permissions and/or ownership issue?  Is what I am trying possible from within an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a bogus driver, e.g. a plain text file, with same name as the real driver, the following sequence seems to get the job done - namely, permanently disabling wifi (until someone restores the device driver).

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su

# turn off wifi just in case...
svc wifi disable

#first make the partition writable as follows: 
mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p5 /system
sync

#go to the folder: 
cd /system/lib/modules
sync

# replace the device driver with a bogus one
cp <path_to_bogus_driver>/wlan.ko /system/lib/modules
sync

# add the reboot so /system gets mounted as it should be
reboot
```